# Is there a best way to find last rows defined by current cell value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataFrame that contains data about sport events. Let's say you see in that a *winner_id*, a *loser_id*, and a *match_id*. I am trying to find the last index of previous contained winner with the same id.
The expected data frame see here:

[image]

```
d = {'winner':["A","B","C","A","A","C","B","D"], 'loser':["B","C","D","D","D","B","A","C"], 'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'id_of_last_winner:' ["", 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

It performs very bad if I iterate trough the columns. The expectation of my code should be like this:
*id_of_last_winner*:

- 1st row: here is nothing because B is the first element.
- 2nd row: 0 because the second element in the winner column is the
  same as the    first in loser column.
- 3rd row: here comes 1 because C is in loser column in 2nd row.
- 4th row: 0 because in winner column A is the first element
- 5th row: 3 because A is the latest element in the winner column.

and so on...

So first intuition was that i iterate trough the loser column with a for loop and then compare the current element with the other elements in loser and winner column. It's straightforward but performs terrible, because each iteration contains 2 other iterations. Is there a better way to speed up that process?

I was hopefull, because I find

```
df['id_of_last_winner'] = data.groupby('winner')['id'].shift()
```

but this checks just the loser column. Any better idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share a sample of the dataframe, not an image. Also share the expected output

Comment: Sorry I wasn't obvious. The image shows the expected dataframe.

Comment: To clarify - you're trying to find the index of the previous match the winner appeared in? What happens if a player wins their first match?

Comment: What makes it confusing, is that the column is called `id_of_last_winner`, but I think you are looking for the index right?

Comment: `0 because the second element in the winner column is the same as the first in loser `, but arent you looking only at the winnder column??

Comment: Yes, I am trying to find the index of the previous match the winner appeared in, but i need to check the winner and the loser columns as well. If a player wins their first match should contain the expectation an empty cell.

Comment: Thats what makes this question complex imo, hes looking in both columns simultaneously.  @yatu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made it a little confusing as you want `id` but the expected output uses `index`. Here's a sample using `id`:

```
# create a list of players
players = list(set(df.winner).union(set(df.loser)) )

# create last game's id for each player
for player in players:
    df[player] = df.id.where((df.winner==player) | (df.loser==player) ).\
                        ffill().shift()

# here's our result
df['winner_last_game'] = df.apply(lambda r: r[r.winner], axis=1)
```

Apparently it is not working if you have a large number of players, but it should work for a couple of hundred players. And here's the output

```
+---+----+--------+-------+-------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------------+
|   | id | winner | loser | id_of_last_winner |  A  |  C  |  D  |  B  | winner_last_game |
+---+----+--------+-------+-------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------------+
| 0 |  1 | A      | B     |                   | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN              |
| 1 |  2 | B      | C     |                 0 | 1.0 | NaN | NaN | 1.0 | 1.0              |
| 2 |  3 | C      | D     |                 1 | 1.0 | 2.0 | NaN | 2.0 | 2.0              |
| 3 |  4 | A      | D     |                 0 | 1.0 | 3.0 | 3.0 | 2.0 | 1.0              |
| 4 |  5 | A      | D     |                 3 | 4.0 | 3.0 | 4.0 | 2.0 | 4.0              |
| 5 |  6 | C      | B     |                 2 | 5.0 | 3.0 | 5.0 | 2.0 | 3.0              |
| 6 |  7 | B      | A     |                 5 | 5.0 | 6.0 | 5.0 | 6.0 | 6.0              |
| 7 |  8 | D      | C     |                 4 | 7.0 | 6.0 | 5.0 | 7.0 | 5.0              |
+---+----+--------+-------+-------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much is a better approach than my was, but as you mentioned the problem is that I have thousands of players.

Comment: Can you please explain why would be easier to use index instead of id?

Comment: Depending on the size of your data as well, `10k players * 100k games` only yields about 4 GB overhead. `index` cannot be used directly with `ffill()`, so if you really want `index`, then you can do `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` and use `index` column in stead of `id`.